# How to refresh Rdata objects in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

My aim is to refresh .Rdata objects when the user confirms a dataset reloading through a shinyalert pop up. A small example below. Before loading the app I've created and saved 2 objects (`DatasetNumber1` and `DatasetNumber2`) containing a label and data to be displayed.

When the app is launched I load by default `DatasetNumber1` objects thanks to the `global.R` file. So now `test` and `data` objects from `DatasetNumber1` are accessible through `server.R` AND `ui.R`, which I need to (not in this example, but in my full app).
I want the user to be able to select the other dataset via the dropdown to refresh the global R objects and in the end the plotting.

The `print` statement in the server.R, after I've selected the other dataset in the dropdown, clicked on the `Load` button and validate through the shinyalert, confirms that the dropdown input changed but the `load` statement does not refresh R objects.

I've tried to make the loading reactive straight in the `global.R` script but I ended with the same result. Maybe the rendering is faster than the loading and so does not take the updated data in account to render...

In any case I do not want to reload neither the app nor the session.

Thanks !

#inputCreation.R

```
test <- "IamDatasetNumber1"
data <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)
save(test, data, file = "./Test/DatasetNumber1.Rdata")

test <- "IamDatasetNumber2"
data <- c(2, 7, 9, 12, 13)
save(test, data, file = "./Test/DatasetNumber2.Rdata")
```

#global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyalert)

load("DatasetNumber1.Rdata")
```

#ui.R

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    div(
        id = "main_page",
        fluidRow( # -------------------------------------------------------
                  column(
                    2, offset=0,
                    selectInput("dropdown_dataset", "Dataset :", choices=c("DatasetNumber1", "DatasetNumber2"), selected="DatasetNumber1")
                  ),
                  column(
                    1, offset=0,
                    useShinyalert(),
                    actionButton("button_dataset", "Load"),
                  )
        ),
        fluidRow( # -------------------------------------------------------
                  uiOutput("test_text")
        ),
        fluidRow( # -------------------------------------------------------
                  plotOutput("test_plot")
        )
    )
  )
)
```

#server.R

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$button_dataset, {
      shinyalert(title = "Are you sure?",
                 text = "This action can take a while",
                 type = "warning",
                 closeOnEsc = TRUE,
                 closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
                 showCancelButton = TRUE,
                 showConfirmButton = TRUE,
                 confirmButtonText = "OK",
                 confirmButtonCol = "#AEDEF4",
                 cancelButtonText = "Cancel",
                 inputId = "shinyalert",
                 callbackR = function(x){
                   if(x){
                     showModal(modalDialog("Loading...", footer=NULL))
                     print(paste(input[["dropdown_dataset"]],sep=""))
                     load(paste(input[["dropdown_dataset"]],".Rdata",sep=""))
                     removeModal()
                   }
                 }
      )
    })
    output$test_text <- renderText(test)
    output$test_plot <- renderPlot(plot(data))
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the initialization of react_data. You should get rid of the `load` from your global file. This way the dataset can be garbage collected when you switch. Otherwise, it will exist in `.GlobalEnv` forever.

Try this server:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {

    react_data <- reactiveVal()
    react_data(local({load("DatasetNumber1.Rdata"); data}))

    observeEvent(
      input$shinyalert,
      {
        req(input$shinyalert)
        load(paste(input$dropdown_dataset,".Rdata",sep=""))
        react_data(data)
      })


    observeEvent(input$button_dataset, {
      shinyalert(title = "Are you sure?",
                 text = "This action can take a while",
                 type = "warning",
                 closeOnEsc = TRUE,
                 closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
                 showCancelButton = TRUE,
                 showConfirmButton = TRUE,
                 confirmButtonText = "OK",
                 confirmButtonCol = "#AEDEF4",
                 cancelButtonText = "Cancel",
                 inputId = "shinyalert",
                 callbackR = function(x){
                   if(x){
                     showModal(modalDialog("Loading...", footer=NULL))
                     print(paste(input[["dropdown_dataset"]],sep=""))
                     removeModal()
                   }
                 }
      )
    })
    output$test_text <- renderText(test)
    output$test_plot <- renderPlot(plot(react_data()))
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit !
In my `Rdata` object I have multiple variables to catch.
Here in your example `test` is unfound

Answer (score 0):

With @Tyler's help !

#server.R

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    
    react <- reactiveVal()
    react(local({load("DatasetNumber1.Rdata"); list(test=test,data=data)}))

    observeEvent(
      input$shinyalert,
      {
        req(input$shinyalert)
        load(paste(input$dropdown_dataset,".Rdata",sep=""))
        react(list(test=test,data=data))
      })


    observeEvent(input$button_dataset, {
      shinyalert(title = "Are you sure?",
                 text = "This action can take a while",
                 type = "warning",
                 closeOnEsc = TRUE,
                 closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
                 showCancelButton = TRUE,
                 showConfirmButton = TRUE,
                 confirmButtonText = "OK",
                 confirmButtonCol = "#AEDEF4",
                 cancelButtonText = "Cancel",
                 inputId = "shinyalert",
                 callbackR = function(x){
                   if(x){
                     showModal(modalDialog("Loading...", footer=NULL))
                     print(paste(input[["dropdown_dataset"]],sep=""))
                     removeModal()
                   }
                 }
      )
    })
    output$test_text <- renderText(react()$test)
    output$test_plot <- renderPlot(plot(react()$data))
  }
)
```